# java devel installation by yum

Tags: rhel, yum, rpm

we are installing the rpm - `java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel-1.8.0.171-8.b10.el7_5.x86_64.rpm`

```
yum  localinstall java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel-1.8.0.171-8.b10.el7_5.x86_64.rpm
Loaded plugins: langpacks
Examining java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel-1.8.0.171-8.b10.el7_5.x86_64.rpm: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel-1.8.0.171-8.b10.el7_5.x86_64
Marking java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel-1.8.0.171-8.b10.el7_5.x86_64.rpm to be installed
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel.x86_64 1:1.8.0.171-8.b10.el7_5 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: java-1.8.0-openjdk(x86-64) = 1:1.8.0.171-8.b10.el7_5 for package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel-1.8.0.171-8.b10.el7_5.x86_64
HighAvailability                                                                                                                                                      | 4.3 kB  00:00:00
ResilientStorage                                                                                                                                                      | 4.3 kB  00:00:00
local                                                                                                                                                                 | 4.3 kB  00:00:00
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel-1.8.0.171-8.b10.el7_5.x86_64 (/java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel-1.8.0.171-8.b10.el7_5.x86_64)
           Requires: java-1.8.0-openjdk(x86-64) = 1:1.8.0.171-8.b10.el7_5
           Installed: 1:java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.161-2.b14.el7.x86_64 (@anaconda/7.5)
               java-1.8.0-openjdk(x86-64) = 1:1.8.0.161-2.b14.el7
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

we can see that

```
Requires: java-1.8.0-openjdk(x86-64) = 1:1.8.0.171-8.b10.el7_5
```

but what we are installing is - java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel-1.8.0.171-8.b10.el7_5.x86_64.rpm

so where is the problem here?

Comment: `java-1.8.0-openjdk-devel` requires `java-1.8.0-openjdk` <- you do see the package names are different?

Comment: what is installed is  rpm -qa | grep java-1.8.0-openjdk
java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.161-2.b14.el7.x86_64
java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.161-2.b14.el7.x86_64

Comment: And clearly those don't match the required version.

Comment: so you suggest to do  yumdownload java-1.8.0-openjdk

Comment: Why installing isolated packages? If dealing with internal machines, I would suggest contemplating an HTTP proxy/spacewalk/satellite for dealing with packages maintenance in a saner way.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro if you look at @yael’s post history, they’re installing an out of date version of RHEL on an isolated network. Judging from the questions, I doubt it’s within the technical grasp of the poster to set up those things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use:

```
--skip-broken
```

or

```
rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```